# How to read a specific text from email body and save it to excel

Tags: python, regex, email, outlook, win32com

Greetings for the day!

I am working on a new project to extract specific data mainly 1) Ticker 2) price 3) Date from email. now email could be of two types a) data comes in email body b) data comes as an attachment. currently, I am focusing on the former, so far what I have done I have created a sub-folder named as Email_Snapper and set some rules so that whatever email I receive from x subject line gets in there.

Now my job is to retrieve specific values as mentioned above and store it in xlsx/csv file in C: drive. i have written the below code but i am literally new to regex family not sure how can this be done, any help on this would be greatly appreciated. The attached screenshot represents a sample format, we get the same ticker, price and date in different formats from different clients, i think i might have to write different functions (script) for each email.

```
import win32com.client
import re
from datetime import datetime
import datetime as dt


EMAIL_ACCOUNT = 'username@email.com'
EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING = 'QIC EUA Index Valuation'
EMAIL_CONTNT = {'Ticker': [], 'TickerLevel': [], 'DATE': []}

out_app = win32com.client.gencache.EnsureDispatch("Outlook.Application")
out_namespace = out_app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
lastWeekDateTime = dt.datetime.now() - dt.timedelta(days=1)
lastWeekDateTime = lastWeekDateTime.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M %p')


root_folder = out_namespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

out_iter_folder = root_folder.Folders['Email_snapper']

char_length_of_search_substring = len(EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING)


item_count = out_iter_folder.Items.Count
Flag = False
cnt = 0
if out_iter_folder.Items.Count > 0:
    for i in range(item_count, 0, -1)[:2]:
        message = out_iter_folder.Items[i]


        #message = message.Restrict("[ReceivedTime] >= '" + lastWeekDateTime + "'")

        Body_content = message.Body

        # Find only mail items and report, note, meeting etc items
        if '_MailItem' in str(type(message)):
            if EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING in message.Subject:
                Flag = True
                string = Body_content
                result = string.split('\n')
                print(result)
```

[image]

my output: no coming column wise, also unable to get rid off the entire paragraph
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This can be easily done with the inbuilt '[csv](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html)' library. Export the excel file as csv, then open it in python. You can read the contents with `[DictReader][2]`. Each line is treated as a dict and you can easily access any value with its column name.

Here is an example:

```
import csv

with open('input_file.csv', 'r') as inputfile:
   input_reader = csv.DictReader(inputfile)

   for line in input_reader:
       print(line["SRAL Ticker Level"])
```

You can save the contents as csv file with `[DictWriter][3]`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several aspects when dealing with the Outlook object model.

First of all, use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` methods of the Items class to get items that correspond to your search criteria instead of iterating over all items in the folder. Read more about them in the following articles:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Second, the following line of code uses the `Body` property which returns a plain text string:

```
message.Body[message.Body.find(r'SRAL'):message.Body.find(r'SRAL Ticker Level')].strip())
```

Instead, I'd suggest dealing with the `HTMLBody` property for extracting values more precisely. The [HTMLBody](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.htmlbody) property returns or sets a string representing the HTML body of the specified item. The `HTMLBody` property should be an HTML syntax string. Setting the `HTMLBody` property will always update the `Body` property immediately.

Also you may consider using the the Word editor. The [WordEditor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff868196(v=office.15).aspx) property of the `Inspector` class returns an instance of the Word `Document` which represents the message body. See [Chapter 17: Working with Item Bodies](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492012%28v=office.12%29.aspx) for more information.

Comment: Hi Eugene, Thanks for looking into it, i am using subject line criteria in my script i think that would suffice ? EMAIL_SUBJ_SEARCH_STRING = 'QIC EUA Index Valuation'

Comment: the problem is not able to fetch specific text values using regx

Comment: Can anyone pls help

Comment: @RahulVaidya Have you tried using `HTMLBody` as suggested? And then perhaps using pandas to read the Html tables: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_html.html There are also plenty of other packages for extracting table data from HTML.

Comment: Hi DS, yes mate i have tried everything i could but i am not getting it